# Push array onto 2D array (matrix) in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

For God only knows what reason, we're being asked to use MATLAB in an AI course. All I want to do is initialize an array, and push arrays onto it. In Ruby, this would be:

```
multi_arr = []
an_arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
multi_arr << an_arr
```

Done! Unfortunately I can't find a similarly simple solution in MATLAB.

Any advice would be extremely appreciated.

EDIT: for the interested, here's the rather ungraceful solution I arrived at:

```
child_states = []
child_state = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

% returns [rows, columns]
dimensions = size(child_states)
child_states(dimensions(1)+1, 1:9) = child_state
```

Comment: I totally understand the frustration.

Comment: Okay, so the problem is that you don't know the length of `child_state` at each iteration?

Comment: In this case I do know the length of child_state. I just don't know how many of the child_state arrays (rows) there will be. I'm frustrated because this is trivial in any other programming language I've ever used

Comment: Are all of the `child_state` vectors the same length? You've got two answers below that will work perfectly fine in this case **without** knowing the number of rows. Another is `child_states(end+1,:) = child_state;` All three will work starting from `[]` to as many rows as you have memory for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can append array to an array in matlab without knowing the dimensions but it won't be very efficient because matlab will allocate space for the whole array each time you do it. Here's how to do it:

```
arrays = [];
arr1 = [1,2];
arr2 = [3,4,5];
% append first array
arrays  = [arrays ,arr1 ]
% append second array
arrays  = [arrays ,arr2 ]
```

arrays =

```
 1     2
```

arrays =

```
 1     2     3     4     5
```

if each of the arrays you want to append have the same length, then you can append them as rows:

```
arrays = [];
arr1 = [1,2,4];
arr2 = [5,6,7];
% append first array
arrays  = [arrays ; arr1 ]
% append second array
arrays  = [arrays ; arr2 ]
```

arrays =

```
 1     2     4
```

arrays =

```
 1     2     4
 5     6     7
```

for more of a ruby like array appending you should use [cell arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html):

```
cells = {};
cells = [cells ,[4,5] ]
cells = [cells ,[1,1,1] ]
cells = [cells ,['hello']]
```

cells =

```
[1x2 double]    [1x3 double]    'hello'
```

Answer (score 1):

GIYF. It seems that you are looking for `horzcat` and `vertcat`. Check out MATLAB's doc at [Creating and concatenating matrices.](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/creating-and-concatenating-matrices.html); from `vertcat` page:

> `C = vertcat(A1,...,AN)` vertically concatenates arrays `A1,...,AN`. All arrays in the argument list must have the same number of columns.
>
> If the inputs are multidimensional arrays, vertcat concatenates N-dimensional arrays along the first dimension. The remaining dimensions must match.

Comment: I've already read that. In every example, you have to know the dimensions of the matrix, which I don't. It happens that with the specific problem, I do know the length of the arrays being pushed, but I don't know how many of these arrays will be pushed.

Comment: Have you tried to iterate several `multi_arr = vertcat(multi_arr, an_arr1)`? I don't have MATLAB here at the moment but it should work. At least, the last time I did it in Octave it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that's supposed to do what you want: concatenate a row vector to an array regardless of size. This function will check the dimension along the second axis of input and output array and pad zero to whichever one that is smaller so they can be concatenated along the first axis.

```
function m = freevertcat(m, n)

    if isempty(m)
        m = cat(1, m, n);
    else
        size_m = size(m, 2);
        size_n = size(n, 2);
        if size_m > size_n 
            n(size_n+1 : size_n + size_m - size_n) = 0
        elseif size_n > size_m
            m(:, size_m+1 : size_m + size_n - size_m) = 0; 
        end
        m = cat(1, m, n);
end
```

example usage

```
m = []
n = [1,2,3,4,5]
m = freevertcat(m,n)
p = [3,3,3]
m = freevertcat(m,p)
```

You'll get

```
m =  1 2 3 4 5
     3 3 3 0 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that just lengths the first array and appends the values in the second array. I'm trying to create a matrix by appending arrays to an array (creating a 2D array)

Comment: You mean you'd like to begin with an empty array and append 2D array of different size to the same array multiple times?

Comment: I'd like to begin with an empty array and append rows to the array, the rows themselves being arrays.

Comment: Do the rows you want to append vary in length or are they always the same length?